# Create and write in a data file using Matlab

Tags: matlab, path

Suppose I have a folder F1 containing two subfolders F11 and F12.
In F11 there is a Matlab file producing some data that I want to save in a .csv file (file1) in F12. I am using `csvwrite` to write data in file1.
How can I create file1 using matlab code ? how can I write in this file without providing the full path to `csvwrite` ?

Comment: The default save location is the `pwd`, present working direction. If you do not want to save there you need to specify the full path.

Comment: Are you asking "How can I make Matlab automatically save in the folder I want it to without telling it where that folder is?"

Comment: @IKavanagh I just want to know if I can provide a partial path since the two subfolders are in the same folder

Comment: @IKavanagh please notice my discussion with Adriaan (below the answer)..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use relative path: `../F12/file1`

Comment: nice! Thank you! (I don't understand why they downvoted the question!?)

Comment: @AngelinaJolly [answers cannot be accepted until the question is at least 15 minutes old](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/250132/why-cant-i-accept-an-answer-in-the-first-15-minutes-after-asking-the-question)

Comment: @mat probably because you comment whether supplying a partial path works. Seeing you have thought of that, it takes 2 seconds to try it. This equates to "shows little effort"

Comment: @Adriaan I was not sure and did not know how to write it ( I was missing the two points ..). That is why :)